# Dynamic Paint to select vertices in edit mode

Tags: vertices, selection-tools, vertex-groups, dynamic-paint

Is there a way to use Dynamic Paint to make a selection of vertices to then be able to delete in edit mode. I would like to use a brush to accurately select a specific shape from a dense mesh. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you trying pressing c on keyboard to select the vertices? You can change the selector size using the mouse wheel and press escape to come out of selection mode.

Answer (score 1):

No. While it appears to be possible at first, the data is only there during the simulation, going into edit mode clears it out.

If it suits your needs, you could [dynamic paint vertex weights](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/dynamic_paint/canvas.html#weight) and use that with a [mask modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/mask.html) to hide part of the mesh.

I expect you will have to use [border, circle or lasso](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/selecting/tools.html#border-select) selection to get the verts you want in edit mode.

Comment: what I was really hoping for is in fact a custom selection brush in the form of geo to make exact complex selections  of another meshes vertices to then be able to delete them. I just thought Dynamics Paint might expose some way to do that. Be great to have this maybe a feature outside the existing selection methods.

Comment: @Bopstar you can use a [boolean modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html) to use a mesh to define the section to be removed from another, when you apply the modifier it becomes real mesh. If you think it can be a new feature, suggest it at [rightclickselect](https://rightclickselect.com).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Boolean operations messes with the geo in a way that just a straight selection would not. I might suggest it as a feature then.